# can't get multi-select field name when post (no choice)

Tags: python, html, tornado, multi-select

html:

```
<form method="post">{% module xsrf_form_html() %}
    <input name="username" type="text">
    <select name="ss" multiple>
        <option value="1">hello</option>
        <option value="2">word</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">提交</button>
</form>
```

tornado:

```
class TestMultiSelectEmptyPost(BaseHandler):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.render('multi-select-empty-post.html')

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print self.request.arguments
```

browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6MLo.png)

server return:

```
{'username': ['aaaa'], '_xsrf': ['xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx']}
```

multi-select field name "ss" is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine whether the user selected **none** of the options, do:

```
ss = self.request.arguments.get("ss")
```

The `get` method returns `None` if there is no value. So,

```
if ss is None:
    print("User selected nothing")
else:
    print("ss = %s" % ss)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing `request.arguments`, I recommend using the [`get_argument`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_argument) method.